# Django upgrade succeeds, then reverts back

Tags: python, django

My django version is 1.1

```
rgross@fun:~$ python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> print django.VERSION
(1, 1, 1, 'final', 0)
>>> quit()
rgross@fun:~$
```

So, I [upgrade to the latest version](http://www.djangoproject.com/download/).

```
gross@fun:/tmp/Django-1.3$ sudo python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_scripts
running install_lib
running install_scripts
changing mode of /usr/local/bin/django-admin.py to 755
running install_data
running install_egg_info
Removing /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3.egg-info
Writing /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3.egg-info
rgross@fun:/tmp/Django-1.3$
```

And check the version again, and great success, I get django 1.3

```
rgross@fun:/tmp/Django-1.3$ python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> print django.VERSION
(1, 3, 0, 'final', 0)
```

BUT, when I open a fresh terminal window and check the version, I find that my version upgrade was not persistent, and the new terminal sees version 1.1!

Any idea what is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was caused because I had also installed django by apt-get.

To resolve:

```
sudo apt-get remove python-django
```